# Does ESP8266 deep sleep make sense while on the power supply?

Tags: power-supply, current, esp8266

If ESP8266 is powered via a dedicated power supply 220V AC → 3.3V DC.

- Is it worth it to put ESP to deep sleep in order to reduce power consumption?

For example the indoor weather station, which makes measurements every hour.

- I figured out that putting ESP to deep sleep definitely worth it when on a battery, but what about power supply?

P.S. This is the [power supply](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/32833671094.html) I suppose to use.

Comment: Probably a purely opinion-based question, but avoiding the waste of power is always good design.

Comment: That's for the end users to decide. Are they ready to pay extra for a device that consumes less?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Good point! I'm not sure that while on sleep mode ESP8266 will consume less. As far as I've understood from the answers below, it depends on the particular power supply used. Some of them could have a standby mode, some not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking the power supply will keep wasting same power whether you use it or not, then you might be wrong.

These power supplies also have a standby state similar to sleeping state of your MCU. When you are not drawing power from these power supplies, they will waste very little power typically 30 mW to 300 mW depending upon design and quality of components used.

Your MCU will not be consuming a lot of power anyways for the kind of application that you mentioned, it might still make sense to put it into deep sleep because you are reducing power wastage (as pointed out by Finbarr in comments). Also, if tomorrow you want to make the gadget battery powered, you do not need to write a new code for it.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if a particular power supply has a standby mode?

Answer (score 1):

> If ESP8266 is powered via a dedicated power supply 220V AC → 3.3V DC, does it worth it to put ESP to deep sleep in order to reduce power consumption?

Adding to whiskeyjack's answer:

Most supplies these days are optimized for very low standby power draw. On a very light load, they will go through a cycle of: stop switching and go to sleep, let the output capacitor power the load, then resume switching once the output voltage has dropped a bit, recharge the output cap, and go back to sleep.

This cycle can occur at audible frequencies, which can make the power supply produce noises like buzz, hiss, whine. Frequency depends on load current.

After testing you might find out that using the deep sleep mode on your ESP cures this problem.